# I need help for applying a logic to this code

Tags: programming

Here's the code:

```
int softStart = A0;
int enable = A1;
int powerBTN = A2, powerState = HIGH, lastPowerState = HIGH;
unsigned long lastDebounceTime = 0;
unsigned long debounceDelay = 25;
unsigned long powerTimer = 0;
unsigned long powerHoldTimer = 0;
bool softStartENB = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(softStart, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enable, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(enable, LOW);
  digitalWrite(softStart, LOW);
  pinMode(powerBTN, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  int powerReading = digitalRead(powerBTN);

  if (powerReading != lastPowerState) {
    lastDebounceTime = millis();
  }

  if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay && !softStartENB) {
    if (powerReading != powerState) {
      powerState = powerReading;
      if (powerState == HIGH) {
        digitalWrite(enable, !digitalRead(enable));
        Serial.print("Normal start: ");
        Serial.println(digitalRead(enable));
      }
    }
  }

  if (powerReading == LOW) {
    powerTimer = millis() - lastDebounceTime;
  } else {
    powerTimer = 0;
  }

  if (powerTimer >= 1000 && millis() - powerHoldTimer >= 2000) {
    softStartENB = 1;
    digitalWrite(enable, LOW);
    digitalWrite(softStart, HIGH);
    Serial.print("Soft start started: ");
    Serial.println(digitalRead(softStart));
    powerHoldTimer = millis();
  }

  if (softStartENB && lastPowerState == HIGH && powerReading == LOW) {
    digitalWrite(enable, HIGH);
    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(softStart, LOW);
    Serial.print("Soft start ended: ");
    Serial.println(digitalRead(softStart));
    softStartENB = 0;
  }

  lastPowerState = powerReading;

}
```

So the logic is as this:

[image]

1. By pressing `powerBTN` the `enable` pin toggles.
2. By holding `powerBTN` for 1 seconds `softStartENB` condition becomes true.
3. When `softStartENB` is true, if I press `powerBTN` again it sets `enable` pin to high and after 2 seconds `softStart` to low.

The problem is that after setting `softStartENB` to 0, `lastPowerState = powerReading` toggles `enable` pin to low but I want `enable` pin to stay high until I press `powerBTN` again to toggle it.

- How can I apply the described logic?

Comment: should `enable` toggle when `powerBTN` is pressed for 1 second?

Comment: @jsotola It can't, because after holding it for a sec the 'softStartENB' flag becomes true and 'enable' can only toggle when 'softStartENB' is flase.

Comment: point `1.` says nothing about `softStartENB` ... also, the `softStartENB` could be false at the beginning of the button press ... should `enable` be toggled when the button is released?

Comment: Your problem statement seems very incomplete. Once `softStartENB` becomes `true`, does it stay `true` forever? If not, which events toggle it back to `false`? Same question for `softStart`: can it ever change from `LOW` to `HIGH`? What happens if the button is pressed during the 2 second delay? Please, try to give a complete description of the desired behavior, preferably in the form of a [state diagram]().

Comment: @jsotola see the edit.

Comment: @EdgarBonet see the edit.

Comment: The device you are controlling has 3 states, OFF,  ON, and IN_SOFT_START. A short press of the button causes the device to toggle between ON and OFF.  A long press initiates IN_SOFT_START. A second press of the button in this state  then puts the device in state ON after waiting 2 seconds. Simple but you should draw it as a conventional state diagram. What about adding a timeout if, after entering state IN_SOFT_START, the user does not press the button again within a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: @6v6gt I can do all these later, right now the problem is that enable pin goes low after softStartENB flag becomes false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using [JC_button](https://github.com/JChristensen/JC_Button) library:

```
#include <JC_Button.h>


const byte softStart(A0), enable(A1);
int powerStates = 0;
bool enableState;

Button powerBTN(A2);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  powerBTN.begin();
  pinMode(enable, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(softStart, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  powerBTN.read();
  Serial.println(powerStates);

  switch (powerStates) {
    case 0:
      if (powerBTN.wasReleased())
        switchEnable();
      else if (powerBTN.pressedFor(1000))
        powerStates = 1;
      break;

    case 1:
      if (powerBTN.wasReleased()){
        digitalWrite(enable, LOW);
        digitalWrite(softStart, HIGH);
        enableState = false;
        powerStates = 2;
      }
      break;
      
    case 2:
      if (powerBTN.wasReleased()){
        digitalWrite(enable, HIGH);
        delay(2000);
        digitalWrite(softStart, LOW);
        enableState = true;
        powerStates = 0;
      }
      break;
  }
}

void switchEnable() {
  enableState = !enableState;
  digitalWrite(enable, enableState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I restructured your code as a finite state machine. There is a minimal number of "foreign" flags and almost a 1:1 relationship between the code and the state diagram.
You can test a simulation of it here: https://wokwi.com/projects/383445446722551809

[image]

```
int softStart = A0;
int enable = A1;
int powerBTN = A2;

enum State { OFF = 0, ON = 1, WAIT_ON = 2 , WAIT_OFF = 3, IN_SOFT_START = 4, SOFT_START_CONFIRM = 5 } ;
State state  ;
State oldState ;
bool stateChange = true ;

uint32_t inCurrentStateAtMs = 0 ;

void setState ( State newState ) {
  // forces change to new state
  inCurrentStateAtMs = millis() ;
  oldState = state ;
  state = newState ;
  stateChange = true ;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(softStart, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enable, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(powerBTN, INPUT_PULLUP) ;
  digitalWrite(enable, LOW);
  digitalWrite(softStart, LOW);

  setState( State::OFF ) ;

}

void loop() {

  if ( stateChange ) {
    //debug
    stateChange = false ;
    Serial.print("state changes to: ");
    Serial.println( state ) ;
  }


  switch ( state ) {

    case State::OFF : {
        if ( ! digitalRead( powerBTN ) && millis() - inCurrentStateAtMs > 100 ) {
          setState( State::WAIT_ON ) ;
        }
        break ;
      }

    case State::WAIT_ON : {
         
          if ( digitalRead( powerBTN ) && millis() - inCurrentStateAtMs < 500 ) {
            digitalWrite( enable, HIGH ) ;
            setState( State::ON );
          }
          else if ( digitalRead( powerBTN ) && millis() - inCurrentStateAtMs >= 500 ) {
            digitalWrite( enable, LOW ) ;
            digitalWrite( softStart, HIGH ) ;
            setState( State::IN_SOFT_START );
          }
         
        break ;
      }

    case State::ON : {
        if ( ! digitalRead( powerBTN ) && millis() - inCurrentStateAtMs > 100 ) {
          setState( State::WAIT_OFF );
        }
        break ;
      }


    case State::WAIT_OFF : {
        if ( digitalRead( powerBTN ) && millis() - inCurrentStateAtMs > 100 ) {
          digitalWrite( enable, LOW ) ;
          setState( State::OFF ) ;
        }
        break;
      }


    case State::IN_SOFT_START : {
        if ( ! digitalRead( powerBTN )  ) {
          digitalWrite( enable, HIGH ) ;
          state = State::SOFT_START_CONFIRM ;
        }
        else if ( millis() - inCurrentStateAtMs > 3000 ) {
          // timeout
          digitalWrite( softStart, LOW ) ;
          setState( State::OFF );
        }
        break ;
      }

    case State::SOFT_START_CONFIRM  : {
        if ( digitalRead( powerBTN ) && millis() - inCurrentStateAtMs > 2000  ) {
          digitalWrite( softStart, LOW ) ;
          setState( State::ON ) ;
        }
        break ;
      }

  } // switch

}  // loop
```

Comment: Please don't change the code behavior, in my code even if the enable pin is high and powerBTN held for 1 second, enable pin goes low. in any case the problem persist, the enable pin doesn't stay/goes high before and after softStart goes high and then low.